# Is there a requirement to use context in OpenSSL MP functions?

Tags: c, openssl, bignum

Part of the functions from `<openssl/bn.h>` take `BN_CTX *ctx` as the last argument.
This is a structure that stores temporary `BIGNUM` variables, allowing you to avoid frequent memory allocation when creating variables with **repeated subroutine calls**.

I thought that using `ctx` is not necessary, because it can only help optimize performance. But this functionality may not be used. For example, I will call the division operation only once.

I also found that in the OpenSSL 1.1.1 version, `BN_mod`, `BN_div` and `BN_mul` worked, even if `NULL` was passed instead of a `ctx` pointer.
In version 3.2.0, this leads to a segmentation fault.

Please explain the logic of using `BN_CTX`.

**UPD:** Minimally reproducible example

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    BIGNUM *a   = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *d   = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *dv  = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *rem = BN_new();
    BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    if(!BN_one(a) || !BN_one(d)) goto err;

    if(!BN_div(dv, rem, a, d, ctx)) goto err; // a / d = (dv, rem)

    if(!BN_print_fp(stdout, dv)) goto err;
    putc('\n', stdout);

    return 1;
err:
    return 0;
}
```

If `NULL` is put in place of `ctx` in `BN_div`, execution will be terminated when using the `BN_div` result (`dv` or `rem`) with the Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: Could you please provide minimum reproducible example

Comment: @ivan_onys please take a look at UPD section